# Obtain data from JSON object with NODE JS

Tags: node.js, json, stringify

I have a response from a webservice like this:

```
[{"record_id":"63","date":"2021-04-12","acept":"1","name":"John","document":"1","passport":"","phone":"999999999","sign":"[document]","activity":"2"}]
```

There is a `var` called `response` that stores that response.
How do I get the "name" and the "phone" from this?

I tried to do `JSON.stringify(response)` in order to get somehow the info but I don't know what to do next.
Is the response a JSON or just a String??
Should I do `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse` to be able to work with this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check to see whether this is a JSON object or string, run `console.log(typeof response)`. If it logs `object`, then this is already a JSON object! You don't have to do anything, and can get attributes out of it like any other object. (For instance, to get the name attribute, you can run `response[0]["name"]`.) If it logs `string`, then you'll have to run `JSON.parse(response)` and save that to a variable to parse the string and turn it into an object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved all my doubts :D!

Answer (score 1):

After parse the response, you can access to name and phone like this:

```js
response[0]["name"]
response[0]["phone"]
```